# The security policy of netfilter on IP Options

Tags: ip, iptables

On BSD, with packetfilter, we have an option allow-opts.
If it's correct, this option permits in IP options in the IP datagram to be an allowed or forbidden traffic.

What is the policy in netfilter? By default, in packetfilter, the traffic is blocked.
I haven't found information in netfilter, which could give me the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try `iptables -m ipv4options -h`